# J Get first N columns of a Matrix

Tags: functional-programming, j

I know that given a Matrix `M` of size NxN I can get the first m rows using `(i.m){M` I would like to know how to get the first n columns from `M`.

I assume that having something like

```
rows =: (i.m){M
```

giving a matrix of size mxN the same approach would be taken to get the first n columns of this new matrix.

edit:

I am trying the use code like this:

```
(i.n)"1{(i.m){M
```

However it is not working as it only returns the first element of the n columns in the first row of M, I need the get n columns.

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer now, but the short story is *verb rank*, one of the foundational concepts in J. Try `(i.n){"1 M`. Or taking a different approach, use *transpose* `(i.n) { |: M`. Or, instead of `{` (*from*) use `{.` (*take*), as in `n {."1 M` or `n {. |: M` or `(_,n) {. M` .

Comment: this worked, I was trying to use the rank in the wrong place. I have gotten a solution, please post yours and I will accept it an the appropriate answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have several answers from Dan. This one is just to explain why you might prefer using *take* instead of *from*. If you run into a case where your n is greater than the number of columns in your M, *take* will give you fill where *from* will produce an error.

```
   $M
10 10
   (i. 3){"1 M
 0  1  2
10 11 12
20 21 22
30 31 32
40 41 42
50 51 52
60 61 62
70 71 72
80 81 82
90 91 92
   3{."1 M
 0  1  2
10 11 12
20 21 22
30 31 32
40 41 42
50 51 52
60 61 62
70 71 72
80 81 82
90 91 92
   (i. 12){"1 M
|index error
|   (i.12)    {"1 M
   12{."1 M
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 0 0
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 0 0
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 0 0
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 0 0
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 0 0
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 0 0
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 0 0
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 0 0
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 0 0
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 0 0
```